# JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment - what issues does it cause?

Tags: java, eclipse, sun

```
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]
```

This seems to be an old error in Eclipse, it's a known bug from a few years ago. I am just wondering:

1. What issues does it cause, as my program seems to run just fine?
2. Any wild clue when will it be fixed?
3. Any way to get rid of it temporarily?

Comment: Added formatting to improve readability. Shifted error message to the top to let people notice it first. Added question to the title to emphasise OP's focus.

Comment: Thank you very much icedwater.